# CodeIgniter PayPal Library , angelleye

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am trying to use the Codeigniter Library and configuring Paypal Express Checkout. Now I keep on getting Error 10410 for an invalid token.
How do I set up the following fields in my Do_express_checkout_payment() function.
‘token’ => ‘ ‘, ‘payerid’ => ‘ ‘,

Answer (score 0):

The token value comes back in the SetExpressCheckout response.  The Payer ID comes back in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response.  You would need to save those in a session variable or something similar so that you can populate DoExpressCheckoutPayment accordingly.